# Extract content of zip string

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have a string of a zip file that contains one single text file.

How could I get the contents of the text file without having to deal with files on the disk?

I tried below solution, but it does not work for me.

```
$written = file_put_contents('php://memory', $zip_string);
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($written) === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('destination');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, use function [extractTo](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php)

[Instalation](http://php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php)

To use this, you must compile PHP with zip support by using the `--enable-zip` configure option.

Comment: By default zip is enabled in my server still not working.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by change the way of data compression. Instance of sending data in a compressed file just add a compression header Content-Encoding on response from server. This header compress your data.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding